# How to remove data from Arraylist by data id

Tags: java, list, struts2, arraylist

I am having problem in removing data from my arraylist by its id. 
I have a books in my arraylist and i want to remove a particular books based on its id. 
I tried the below code but my data is not removing.

Please check my code below and suggest a solution for it.

**Update**
When i calls this method then compiler reads all the below code but it does not removes my data from my arraylist. I am not getting any error.

```
  -------------------
  -------------------
   public String removebookfrmSession()
    {  
        List<Bookdetails> books = new ArrayList<Bookdetails>();
        String bookid = request.getParameter("bkid");    
        Bookdetails book = dao.listBookDetailsById(Integer.parseInt(bookid));
        books = (ArrayList) session.get(BillTransactionBooksConstants.BOK);
        if ( books == null ) books = new ArrayList<Bookdetails>();
        boolean already_exists = false;
        for ( Bookdetails b : books ) 
        {
            if ( Integer.toString(b.getId()).equals(bookid))
            {
                already_exists = true; 
                break;
            }
        }
        if (book != null && already_exists  ) 
        { 
            books.remove(book);
            System.out.println("books size"+books.size()); 
            session.put(BillTransactionBooksConstants.BOK,books);
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Bookdetails.java (POJO)

```
        package v.esoft.pojos;

    // Generated Nov 5, 2012 9:37:14 PM by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1

    import java.util.Date;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.persistence.Temporal;
    import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

    /**
     * Bookdetails generated by hbm2java
     */
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "bookdetails", catalog = "vbsoftware")
    public class Bookdetails implements java.io.Serializable {

        private Integer id;
        private String isbn;
        private String bookTitile;
        private String authFirstname;
        private String authLastname;
        private String editionYear;
        private Integer subjectId;
        private Integer coverId;
        private Integer languageId;
        private String publisherName;
        private Integer editionId;
        private Float price;
        private String quantity;
        private String description;
        private Integer locationId;
        private String remarks;
        private String img1;
        private String img2;
        private String videoUrl;
        private Integer createrId;
        private Date createdDate;
        private Integer updateId;
        private Date updatedDate;

        public Bookdetails() {
        }

        public Bookdetails(String isbn, String bookTitile, String authFirstname,
                String authLastname, String editionYear, Integer subjectId,
                Integer coverId, Integer languageId, String publisherName,
                Integer editionId, Float price, String quantity,
                String description, Integer locationId, String remarks,
                String img1, String img2, String videoUrl, Integer createrId,
                Date createdDate, Integer updateId, Date updatedDate) {
            this.isbn = isbn;
            this.bookTitile = bookTitile;
            this.authFirstname = authFirstname;
            this.authLastname = authLastname;
            this.editionYear = editionYear;
            this.subjectId = subjectId;
            this.coverId = coverId;
            this.languageId = languageId;
            this.publisherName = publisherName;
            this.editionId = editionId;
            this.price = price;
            this.quantity = quantity;
            this.description = description;
            this.locationId = locationId;
            this.remarks = remarks;
            this.img1 = img1;
            this.img2 = img2;
            this.videoUrl = videoUrl;
            this.createrId = createrId;
            this.createdDate = createdDate;
            this.updateId = updateId;
            this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        public Integer getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Column(name = "isbn", length = 90)
        public String getIsbn() {
            return this.isbn;
        }

        public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
            this.isbn = isbn;
        }

        @Column(name = "book_titile")
        public String getBookTitile() {
            return this.bookTitile;
        }

        public void setBookTitile(String bookTitile) {
            this.bookTitile = bookTitile;
        }

        @Column(name = "auth_firstname", length = 120)
        public String getAuthFirstname() {
            return this.authFirstname;
        }

        public void setAuthFirstname(String authFirstname) {
            this.authFirstname = authFirstname;
        }

        @Column(name = "auth_lastname", length = 120)
        public String getAuthLastname() {
            return this.authLastname;
        }

        public void setAuthLastname(String authLastname) {
            this.authLastname = authLastname;
        }

        @Column(name = "edition_year", length = 20)
        public String getEditionYear() {
            return this.editionYear;
        }

        public void setEditionYear(String editionYear) {
            this.editionYear = editionYear;
        }

        @Column(name = "subject_id")
        public Integer getSubjectId() {
            return this.subjectId;
        }

        public void setSubjectId(Integer subjectId) {
            this.subjectId = subjectId;
        }

        @Column(name = "cover_id")
        public Integer getCoverId() {
            return this.coverId;
        }

        public void setCoverId(Integer coverId) {
            this.coverId = coverId;
        }

        @Column(name = "language_id")
        public Integer getLanguageId() {
            return this.languageId;
        }

        public void setLanguageId(Integer languageId) {
            this.languageId = languageId;
        }

        @Column(name = "publisher_name", length = 70)
        public String getPublisherName() {
            return this.publisherName;
        }

        public void setPublisherName(String publisherName) {
            this.publisherName = publisherName;
        }

        @Column(name = "edition_id")
        public Integer getEditionId() {
            return this.editionId;
        }

        public void setEditionId(Integer editionId) {
            this.editionId = editionId;
        }

        @Column(name = "price", precision = 12, scale = 0)
        public Float getPrice() {
            return this.price;
        }

        public void setPrice(Float price) {
            this.price = price;
        }

        @Column(name = "quantity", length = 40)
        public String getQuantity() {
            return this.quantity;
        }

        public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }

        @Column(name = "description", length = 65535)
        public String getDescription() {
            return this.description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        @Column(name = "location_id")
        public Integer getLocationId() {
            return this.locationId;
        }

        public void setLocationId(Integer locationId) {
            this.locationId = locationId;
        }

        @Column(name = "remarks", length = 65535)
        public String getRemarks() {
            return this.remarks;
        }

        public void setRemarks(String remarks) {
            this.remarks = remarks;
        }

        @Column(name = "img1")
        public String getImg1() {
            return this.img1;
        }

        public void setImg1(String img1) {
            this.img1 = img1;
        }

        @Column(name = "img2")
        public String getImg2() {
            return this.img2;
        }

        public void setImg2(String img2) {
            this.img2 = img2;
        }

        @Column(name = "video_url", length = 65535)
        public String getVideoUrl() {
            return this.videoUrl;
        }

        public void setVideoUrl(String videoUrl) {
            this.videoUrl = videoUrl;
        }

        @Column(name = "creater_id")
        public Integer getCreaterId() {
            return this.createrId;
        }

        public void setCreaterId(Integer createrId) {
            this.createrId = createrId;
        }

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "created_date", length = 19)
        public Date getCreatedDate() {
            return this.createdDate;
        }

        public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
            this.createdDate = createdDate;
        }

        @Column(name = "update_id")
        public Integer getUpdateId() {
            return this.updateId;
        }

        public void setUpdateId(Integer updateId) {
            this.updateId = updateId;
        }

        @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "updated_date", length = 19)
        public Date getUpdatedDate() {
            return this.updatedDate;
        }

        public void setUpdatedDate(Date updatedDate) {
            this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should use `Iterator` then call `remove`. Or provide equals based on `bookid`

Comment: What problem are you facing? Any exceptions, errors, or unexpected output? Please post the relevant stuffs. And why are you having that: - `return SUCCESS`. I see an undefined variable there.

Comment: @RohitJain I updated. Please check my info.

Comment: @AmitD I updated my code please check.

Comment: Do you really need to check if it exists first? Could you use call the arraylist.remove() to remove the object from the list once you get it from the list? So book = "get book by id", then books.remove(book). As long as the bookdetail class has an unique identifier setup, that should work.

Comment: @Logan Can you post this as answer for this question. Because i am not understanding what you are trying to  explain.

Comment: @AmitD Why you deleted your answer it was correct. I was getting correct output. Please post your previous answer for my problem. I am waiting..

Comment: @user1726508 The reason was equality based on reference is not a good idea. You should override equals

Comment: @AmitD What do you mean by "The reason was equality based on reference is not a good idea. You should override equals "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Bookdetails` class must implement the `public boolean equals(Object o)` method in order to use the `List#remove(Object o)` method. Otherwise, you should handle the object removal by yourself as stated by @juergend.

Implementing the `equals` method would be like this:

```
public class Bookdetails {
    private int id;
    //other attributes and methods...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Bookdetails) {
            Bookdetails oBookdetails = (Bookdetails)o;
            return (this.id == oBookdetails.id);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now the `books.remove(book);` would work without need of the `for ( Bookdetails b : books )` loop.

Comment: i written this method `@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {` inside my Bookdetails  pojo class. But IDE is showing error .  Error:  **Multiple markers at this line
 - This method must return a result of type 
  boolean
 - overrides java.lang.Object.equals**

Answer (score 1):

Default equality is based on `reference` so you need to assign `book` to reference from the `list` so that `remove` will work. Or you can override `equals` but I am not quite sure whether you can provide equality on `bookId`

```
for ( Bookdetails b : books ) 
{
    if ( Integer.toString(b.getId()).equals(bookid))
    {
        already_exists = true;
        book= b; 
        break;
    }
}
```

Then when you call `remove` because of reference equality it will remove `book`

**Update:**

If its POJO and you have `primary key` then you can easily implement equals on `primary key` that is `id`. No need to iterate over the list.